# replacing specific characters in strings

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, pug, html-entities

pretty simple:

i have mathematical problems stored in a DB, like `3+6`, `5*3`, `4-2` etc.

i want the output to show proper mathematical ×s instead of * (and ÷ instead of /).
but they have to be stored in the DB with * and / for obvious reasons (being "normal" characters vs. html entities in DB and especially for mathjs to be able to solve them from string)

so i am looking for a way to change them in the html output.
first i thought about something with css, but that would probably mean i'd have to have a class for them (or is it possible?).
then i thought i could do it with jS/jQuery. but it feels overly complicated at first.

how would you do this?

(server is running node.js + jade. the strings come from the db and are rendered directly on the page, so i need a way to change the symbols "afterwards")

Comment: It might be more suitable to do this on the server side. What language are you using there? Php? Can you show some code?

Comment: it's node. too much code to show i guess. but as i said, it has to be saved this way, so that mathjs can solve it (and check if given answers were correct etc)

Comment: I would then add nodejs to the tags of your question.

Comment: I also see you use jade. Please tag your question with that.

Comment: sry i thought it wasn't that important to know, as the problem itself is based on the final result

Comment: You never know what nodejs and jade experts can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

You don't necessarily have to store the characters as HTML entities. So long as you include the appropriate charset meta tag, then you'll be able to use unicode symbols in your page.

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

If you can't store them in the database as unicode, then you'll have to programatically fix the strings afterwards.

```
var replacementSymbols: {
  '*': '×',
  '/': '÷'
};

function replaceInString(equation) {
  var targetSymbols = Object.keys(replacementSymbols);

  return targetSymbols.reduce(function(string, symbol) {
    var replacement = replacementSymbols[symbol];
    return string.replace(symbol, replacement);
  }, equation);
}
```

Comment: i could probably store them, sure. but i need those symbols to solve and check answers with mathjs.
i guess i'll try your second idea, that should do

Answer (score 0):

What you're attempting to do is not really possible with CSS.

You could use JavaScript's string replace method to achieve this instead.
for instance:

```
var str = "5*6"
var res = str.replace("*", "×");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: but if i want to do it globally on the whole page? i.e. without having the string in a var (page is rendered with jade)

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing your html, you can insert a `<span class='multiply'></span>` for each *

Then you can do:

```
$("span.multiply").html("×");
```

And then you you would do the same with division, and so on.

**EDIT**

You could also try something like this:

```
var newHtml = $('body').html().replace(/\*/g, "×");
$('body').html(newHtml);
```

Comment: the problems are generated with a string attribute like "3*5" as a member. then passed to jade and inserted into the final page. i can't insert classes before the page is rendered

Comment: @user3787706 I see. Does what I am showing in my edit work for you then?

Comment: this should work, yes. that was what i was thinking about :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using something like Angular and a filter to parse the string, something like this might be the best option.  If you're not able to insert classes before the page is rendered, you may need to see if the rendered data is wrapped in something like `<pre/>` tag so that you can use the appropriate selector:

**template**

```
<div class="math-expression">
    3 * 4 = 12
</div>
```

**logic**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.math-expression').forEach( 
    function( elem, i, arr){
         s = elem.textContent
         elem.textContent = s.replace( /\*/g, 'x' )
    }
 )
```

**note**

*I didn't test this as I normally just use Angular filters for these types of text renderings.*

Comment: i think this is the best answer. i CAN wrap it in a class, so i can select properly, instead of replacing symbols on the whole page. thanks

Comment: @jusopi keep in mind that this usage of replace will only replace the first instance of * inside the div

Comment: @user3787706 I would definitely recommend wrapping it in a class. I was assuming you couldn't wrap anything.

Comment: something with /g should fix that, right?
/\*/g ? i hate regex :/

Comment: @berzerk - you're right, I hadn't thought of more complex algebraic expressions.  Updated the answer.